# Windows 2008 Server in Amazon EC2 stops responding when SSTP/VPN connection is closed

Tags: windows, vpn, amazon-web-services

All,

I have a single Windows 2008 server running in Amazon's EC2 cloud.  It's running a web application that is running fine and is accessible to the outside world.

I need 3-5 developers to be able to work on database on the server, and was intending to accomplish this by setting up SSTP/RRAS on the server and letting them VPN in.

This has been a bit of an ordeal due to the amount of server roles and messing with certificates that has been needed, but my VPN connection works now (all clients will be Windows 7).

My problem is that when I use my VPN connection (from the client side) the server hangs - although not at any any consistent place, sometimes it's when I close the connection, some times when I'm making the connection).  The only way that I've found to get it back is to reboot it from the Amazon management console.

Thanks for any guidance.

Duncan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue sounds very similar to that faced by the people who have posted here:
http://www.winvistatips.com/vpn-acces-sbs-2008-kills-routung-and-remote-access-service-t672538.html

It hasn't occurred again since so I'm no longer troubleshooting it.  It was very annoying for a day or so though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems quite a common problem with Amazon EC2.  This forum thread is one of many:
http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/message.jspa?messageID=168816